# Setting freemarker template from classpath

Tags: freemarker

I have a web application that I need to manually obtain a Freemarker template - the template is obtained via a class in a library project, but the actual tpl file is contained in the web application classpath.  So, there are 2 projects, one 'taac-backend-api' and another 'taac-web'; taac-backend-api has the code to grab the template, and process it, but taac-web is where the template is stores (specifically in: WEB-INF/classes/email/vendor.tpl) - I have tried everything from using springs classpath resource to using Freemarkers setClassForTemplateLoading method.  I assume this would work:

```
    freemarkerConfiguration = new Configuration();
    freemarkerConfiguration.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "");
    Template freemarkerTemplate = freemarkerConfiguration.getTemplate("/email/vendor.tpl");
```

yet, I always get a FileNotFoundException.  Can someone explain the best way to obtain a template from the classpath?

Thanks.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

this is what ended up working for me:

```
freemarkerConfiguration = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_28);
freemarkerConfiguration.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "/");
Template freemarkerTemplate = freemarkerConfiguration.getTemplate("email/vendor.tpl");
```

Comment: Please where suppose "email/vendor.tpl" to be ?

Answer (score 11):

In 2017, the following is deprecated:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
```

We should pass `freemarker.template.Version` to the constructor:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration(new Version(2, 3, 23));
conf.setClassForTemplateLoading(Application.class, "/views");
```

where the version numbers refer to the current version of FreeMarker.

The `views` directory is located in `src/main/resources`.

Answer (score 5):

```
freemarkerConfiguration = new Configuration();
freemarkerConfiguration.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "");
Template freemarkerTemplate = freemarkerConfiguration.getTemplate("template.tpl");
```

Use this method to load the classes from the package where your class is located, so if your class is

`org.foo.SomeClass` the templates will be looked for in `/org/foo` in the classpath. This keeps your templates stored with the class that uses/loads them.

Comment: But if I want to keep the template in under resoources/template folder, how can i do that?

Comment: @Aromal found any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Struts 2 and the Conventions plugin, wuntee's solution doesn't seem to work: `setClassForTemplateLoading` in turn creates an instance of `ClassTemplateLoader` which doesn't find files in jars no matter what path prefix is specified.

Instead, create an instance of `StrutsClassTemplateLoader`. (I do this in a custom sub-class of `FreemarkerManager` in its `getTemplateLoader` method.)  It takes no parameters, so presumably it just knows how Struts and Conventions do things.

Comment: Depending on the class loader hierarchy, sometimes it has to be considered carefully what class you specify for `ClassTemplateLoader`. Often the best is to use the `ClassTemplateLoader` constructor that takes a `ClassLoader` directly (instead of a `Class` - since 2.3.22), and then passing in the thread context class loader of the web application.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following config and place it in application properties.

```
spring.freemarker.template-loader-path=
```