# freemarker: template Loader : load templates from zip file

Tags: freemarker

is it possible to load freemarker templates from zip file?

i want to zip all templates in a single file and put it in my application.

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be ideal, but if you would just [load the text of the zipped template](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util.zip/how-to-read-zip-file.html) files you can instantiate a FreeMarkerTemplate from the String.  I gave you an example of how it might be done below, but I suggest reading [the freemarker documentation](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/index.html) as well. (check the Getting Started tab)

i.e.

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
//configuring default free marker configuration
cfg.setObjectWrapper(new DefaultObjectWrapper());

//construct template from string
String templateText = "";//load template text from zip file

Template template= new Template("sometemplate", new StringReader(templateText), cfg);

//your data model 
Object root = new Object(); 

//process template 
StringWriter out = new StringWriter(); 
template.process(new Object(), out); 

String renderedText= out.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a zip file, but you can load them up from a jar file using the 'classForTemplateLoading' feature:

```
public class MyLoader 
{
    private static Configuration cfg = new Configuration();

    static 
    {
         cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading( MyLoader.class, "/" );
    }

    public Template getTemplate( String path ) throws Throwable
    {
         return cfg.getTemplate(path);
    }
}
```

For example, if your template "MyTemplate.ftl" is in the 'com.mycode.templates' package, the path would be "/com/mycode/templates/MyTemplate.ftl".

So then you would jar up your 'source' tree as if it were classes, add the jar to your classpath and it should all just work.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019424/setting-freemarker-template-from-classpath