# FreeMarker template loading issue

Tags: java, freemarker

I have java application packaged into *myApplication.jar* having following structure:

- com

  - mypackages
- templates
  ..
  ..

**Issue** is How do i pass templates location **dir** to configuration?
I have tried with Spring Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/templates/");
but that throws exception when at **resource.getFile()**

My Configuration initialization code:

```
cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.setCacheStorage(new freemarker.cache.MruCacheStorage(20, 250));
cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(dir);
cfg.setObjectWrapper(new DefaultObjectWrapper());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019424/setting-freemarker-template-from-classpath?rq=1)

```
cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(getClass(), "/templates");
```